# Subdirectory and index.html

Tags: html

Say I have a website with the following pages:

- Home
- About
- Services

  - Service1
  - Service2
- Contact

Currently, I've stored the website with this structure:

- index.html
- about.html
- services/

  - service1.html
  - service2.html
- service.html
- contact.html

In practice, should about.html, service.html, contact.html be in their own subdirectories and renamed as index.html so it is easily accessible? Similarly, should service1.html and service2.html be in their own subdirectories within services?

I ask this as I am not sure how I should exactly layout the pages, and it is probably more ideal to remove the .html bit of the pages by just accessing the relevant subdirectory. Thanks for any help

Comment: Depends on if you want your urls look like `site.com/about.html` or `site.com/about/`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove .html for subdirectory

for site.com/services

just create new folder services1  under main folder and copy  service1.html to it and rename as index.html

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I know that method works, but is it common practice to do so?